# XSLT remove last comma in Json Array when Array Length is not defined

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have to build JSON payload with details of authors, depending on several business logic. For this I'm using XSLT 2.0 within WSO2 EI. A sample of xslt is mentioned below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://example.com/x">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:param name="param1" />
    <xsl:param name="param2" />
    <xsl:param name="param3" />
    <xsl:param name="param4" />
    <xsl:param name="param5" />

    <xsl:function name="x:setAuthor">
        <xsl:param name="p1" />
        <xsl:param name="p2" />
        <xsl:text>
            {"name": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$p1" /><xsl:text>",
             "age": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$p2" /><xsl:text>"
             },</xsl:text>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>
        {"booksDetails": [{
   "book": {"title": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$param1" /><xsl:text>"},
   "authors":    [
   </xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$param1 = 'book-sample1'">
                <xsl:value-of select="x:setAuthor('John', '35')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="$param2 = 'true' and $param3 = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:setAuthor('Perera', '40')" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:setAuthor('Mark', '50')" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$param2 = 'true' and $param4 = 'true' and $param5 = 'true'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:setAuthor('Larry', '60')" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="x:setAuthor('Elen', '28')" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <!-- There are lots of logics to set authors -->
        <xsl:text>
   ]
}]}
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here I have a function to create a common author element. It's like below.

```
        {
            "name": "<name>",
            "age": "<age>"
         },
```

Everything else is working fine, but the issue is, this sets a comma (,) for the last author element as well. Appreciate your valuable ideas to overcome this.

NOTE: In this case, I cannot use the following as I don't know the array count. It can be varied according to logic.

> ```
> <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
>      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
> </xsl:if>
> ```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You don't need to know the array count. You need to select a sequence of nodes and the  the stylesheet will count them for you.

Comment: This is not like converting the existing payload directly. We are building JSON payload according to some logic. Therefore I'm confused how to get the sequence of nodes.

Comment: You could store all authors first in a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First store the authors in a variable and after that create your json-array.
i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:x="http://example.com/x" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="param1"/>
  <xsl:param name="param2"/>
  <xsl:param name="param3"/>
  <xsl:param name="param4"/>
  <xsl:param name="param5"/>

  <xsl:function name="x:setAuthor">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="age"/>
    <xsl:text> {"name": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$name"/><xsl:text>", "age": "</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$age"/><xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable as="element(author)*" name="autheurs">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$param1 = 'book-sample1'">
          <author age="35" name="John"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:if test="$param2 = 'true' and $param3 = 1">
            <author age="40" name="Perera"/>
            <author age="50" name="Mark"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$param2 = 'true' and $param4 = 'true' and $param5 = 'true'">
            <author age="60" name="Larry"/>
            <author age="28" name="Elen"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:text>{"booksDetails": [{
         "book": {"title": "</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$param1"/><xsl:text>"},
         "authors": [
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$autheurs">
      <xsl:value-of select="x:setAuthor(@name, @age)"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- There are lots of logics to set authors -->
    <xsl:text>
         ]
      }]}
          </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This did the trick!! Thanks a lot! You saved my time :)